# Printing C# console contents

Tags: c#, printing, console

I currently have a list of information on the console screen id like to print when typing "print" is there a way to grab the contents of the console and print the text information?

Comment: Please, provide some codes of your program

Comment: By "print" do you mean "send to the printer"? Is this output that your own program has created, or would it be on the user's console for some other reason? Your question is unclear at the moment.

Comment: do you know how the data go to the screen? By a programm of your own? If not: By a another program writing to StdOut? (You can test this by running it with its output redirected like this: `some.exe > c:\\text.txt` If the stuff you want is in the new file you can use the redirection on the process, too. If not you need to read the screen..)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the whole content in a string attribute and then print it.

```
string wholeText;
wholeText += "more text\n";

string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
if (userInput.Equals("print", StringComparisson.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine(wholeText);
    //Or export to a file, send to printer...
}
```

**EDIT**: Code improvement

```
StringBuilder wholeText = new StringBuilder();
wholeText.Append("more text\n");

string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
if (userInput.Equals("print", StringComparisson.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine(wholeText.ToString());
    //Or export to a file, send to printer...
}
```

Comment: Excessive string concatenation is probably not a great idea.

Comment: @RavB `StringBuilder` to the rescue!

Comment: @cubrr I would lean towards using something that inherits from `TextWriter` and filter out the PRINT command.

Comment: How is that grabbing the sceen content?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to do two things here:

1. Capture standard output
2. Send standard output to printer

To capture standard output of your application, explore the [Console.SetOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx) method to feed into a type of `TextWriter`, probably a `StringWriter`.

Once this output is captured, you can print that stream using the [PrintDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  The example linked reads directly from a stream.

Comment: Assuming the screen was filled by via StdOut (or StdErr). What if not?